# Indexed view's indexes are disabling when I rebuild ALL indexes in one of the view's parent tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an indexed view which ends up with it's primary key and its other indexes disabled after
I rebuild ALL the indexes in one of the view's parent tables ?

The table that I rebuild All on is the main table in the indexed view ??

Any suggestions please - this has me baffled.

I have increased the disk space of the actual storage so space is not a problem ?

Comment: That's odd. If it were me, I'd set up a DDL trigger in the database in question to capture everything in the DDL_INDEX_EVENTS group for that table and see what's causing it.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  You say to set it up for a table, but can I set it up for an indexed view ?

Comment: I mis-spoke, but the DDL_INDEX_EVENTS group (to my knowledge) will capture events for any index, regardless of whether it's on an table or view. Try it out in a test environment wherein you set up the trigger and then do an explicit `alter index ... disable` and make sure that the event gets captured.

Comment: I think it was a cardinality thing with the primary Key ?
We were creating an indexed view with a PK and on non-clustered index, then we were populating the main table underneath the view which was empty when we created the indexed view ?
I noticed when we inserted the data (24.5 million rows), the indexed view's PK and index were disabled.
I have changed the PK of the indexed view and now it creates even with the data there ?  

Any ideas please ?

Comment: The idea that I already gave you (setting up the ddl trigger) should tell you not only when the index is being called, but by whom, on what machine, what the statement text is, etc. It sounds like you're doing some sort of ETL ("...when we inserted the data"). If so, my bet would be that that process is explicitly disabling the indexed view to make the ETL go faster. But let's not guess: set up the ddl trigger and *know*.

Comment: Thanks for that Ben - No - no ETL job - Just a massive hourly Merge job - then switch the staging table to live (24.5 million rows approx) - I will look at DDL_INDEX_EVENTS in a trigger idea - very useful.

Comment: Hi Ben
I built the suggested trigger, but there is nothing in the new table storing the trigger information to suggest what was causing the disabling ???

Comment: Let's take it up in chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64438/indexed-views-indexes-are-disabling-when-i-rebuild-all-indexes-in-one-of-the-vie